# How to represent an integer with multiple digits? e.g represent 1 as 01

Tags: iphone, integer, int, nslog

How could I NSLog/Output to a label an integer such as 7 as 07 rather than just 7?

I've tried %ii and %2i without success, and searched all over Google for a solution!

Surely there's a way to do it!?

Anyone? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NSLog/printf format allows `%02d`.

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
NSLog(@"%02d",07)
```

It will output: 07

Answer (score 0):

```
NSNumberFormatter *numFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numFormatter setPaddingCharacter:@"0"];
[numFormatter setFormatWidth:2];
NSString *paddedString = [numFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:integer]];
[numFormatter release];
```

Comment: Thanks, useful for future but the %02d thing's good for me now.